# Open all notebooks in Working mode?

Tags: front-end, notebooks, options, display

Is there a way to specify this as a global setting that oversides an individual notebook screen environment setting?

**Motivation:** I have a folder of many slideshows and need to change this manually each time I open one.

**What I've tried:** Setting the `ScreenStyleEnvironment` in the options inspector globally doesn't work for notebooks you haven't opened yet:

[image]

Comment: But if you open->change->save then you don't need to do this each time you open one, right? Anyway, you can scan files in directory with `open + SetOptions[nb, ScreenStyleEnvironment  -> "Working"]`+save+close`.